# Python Selenium: Finds h1 element but returns empty text string

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, hidden

I am trying to get the text in the header on this [page](https://www.ishares.com/uk/institutional/en/products/251805/?siteEntryPassthrough=true&referrer=tickerSearch&locale=en_GB&userType=institutional):

[image]

> iShares FTSE MIB UCITS ETF EUR (Dist)

The tag looks like this:

```
<h1 class="product-title" title="iShares FTSE MIB UCITS ETF EUR (Dist)"> iShares FTSE MIB UCITS ETF EUR (Dist) </h1>
```

I am using this xPath:

```
xp_name = ".//*[@class[contains(normalize-space(.), 'product-title')]]"
```

Retrieving via `.text` in Selenium WebDriver for Python:

```
new_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xp_name).text
```

The driver finds the xpath, but when I print `new_name`, macOS Terminal only prints a blank string: `""`

What could be the reason for this?

[image]

---

Note: I also tried some other xpath alternatives, getting the same result, for example with:

```
xp_name = ".//*[@id='fundHeader']//h1"
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem is that there are two `h1` elements with totally the same outer `HTML`: the first is hidden, the second is not. You can check it with

```
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h1[@class="product-title "]')))
```

`text` property allow you to get text from **only visible** elements while `textContent` attribute also allow to get text of **hidden one**

Try to replace

```
new_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xp_name).text
```

with

```
new_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xp_name).get_attribute('textContent')
```

or simply handle the second (visible) header:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h1[@class="product-title "]')[1].text
```

Comment: Might or might not be relevant: For me the problem was that the element I was trying to fetch just wasn't loaded yet. So a 'time.sleep(1)' fixed it for me. The way the website was setup, it wouldn't throw an error tho.

Comment: Just want to say Thank You for this answer. Spent couple of hours trying to figure out why i get " " in 
scraping results, only after i added .get_attribute('textContent') i got my desired output

Answer (score 1):

As @ahmad-moussa mentioned, for me to the solution was:

```
import time
```

(...)

```
time.sleep(1)
# before 
<webelement>.text
```