# Selenium returns empty string instead of the actual data

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium via Python in attempts to web scrape. I'm almost where I want to be but I ran into what I am now realizing is not so small of a problem. So the element I am working with is this:

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-current-day ui-datepicker-today" 
data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="3" data-year="2018">
    <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" href="#">10
    </a>
</td>
```

My ultimate goal is to get the 10 that's between the a tags. This is my code so far:

```
option = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" - incognito")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
browser.get(myUrl)
calendar = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]')
viewCal = browser.find_element_by_name('choice_set[begin_at]')
viewCal.click()

row = calendar.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

column = calendar.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
numb = column[0].find_element_by_tag_name('a')
numb.text
```

`numb.text` returns `''` instead of 10.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So, how is going? Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
numb.get_attribute("innerText")
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. can you think of a reason why this works but not the property method

Answer (score 4):

The `text` & `innerText` does only work with visible elements
If you want to get the text of a hidden element
then `textContent` could be an option

```
get_attribute("textContent")
```

Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43430097/14454151

Answer (score 3):

Core logic for get **text** from [WebElement](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement)：

- `webElement.text`
- `webElement.get_attribute("innerText")`
- `webElement.get_attribute("textContent")`

Full code:

```py
def getText(curElement):
    """
    Get Selenium element text

    Args:
        curElement (WebElement): selenium web element
    Returns:
        str
    Raises:
    """
    # # for debug
    # elementHtml = curElement.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    # print("elementHtml=%s" % elementHtml)

    elementText = curElement.text # sometime NOT work

    if not elementText:
        elementText = curElement.get_attribute("innerText")

    if not elementText:
        elementText = curElement.get_attribute("textContent")

    # print("elementText=%s" % elementText)
    return elementText
```

Calll it:

```py
curTitle = getText(h2AElement)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't select the right WebElements in your code.

I tried the following code with a similar datepicker and it was printing the expected daynumber.

```
days = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui-state-default"]')
daynumber = days[12].text
print(daynumber)
```

Comment: It is returning None :(  Do you have any idea why this might be so?

Comment: @Chae I changed my answer can you check it again

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author.)*

I am very confused about why this is so but I guess I went in too deep.  I skipped the last two steps of my code and finished with `column[0].text` instead and that worked!  Also as Ratmir answered on the bottom `numb.get_attribute("innerText")` also gives the correct answer.