# No text in Selenium element which definitely contains text

Tags: python, selenium

So, I've got a Selenium webdriver running. I want to extract text from some nodes. I can find them:

```
In [73]: nodes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("rect > title")
In [74]: len(nodes)
Out[74]: 63
```

But they don't contain any text:

```
In [75]: for n in nodes:
    ...:     if n.text:
    ...:         print(n.text)
<prints nothing>
```

But if I open devtools in browser which is connected to this instance of driver, I find the same amount of nodes with this CSS selector - and they definitely contain some text:
[image: Devtools]

So, I've got some nodes with text which is not retrivable by Selenium. Just to make sure, I created a BeautifulSoap from that page's source - and I was able to find elements in question that way and get their text.

```
In [86]: [a.text for a in s.select("rect > title")]
Out[86]: 
['Sometext',
 'Sometext',
 'Sometext',
 'Sometext',
 ...]
```

Getting "innerText" instead, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748736/selenium-returns-empty-string-instead-of-the-actual-data/49750517) question, didn't help. Is that some kind of Selenium bug, or I am doing something wrong? Just in case, [there](https://gist.github.com/keddad/0aeeab3c356b1a222dd3faedc006e2f7) is problematic html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

> n.getAttribute("textContent")

It's possible that the "title" tag is getting handled special because "it's not rendered":
https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-element-text

Comment: That worked! Weird, though, since they looked like they were rendered. Still, thanks

Comment: I bet it's special handling in the code for webelemetns that are "title" tags... Can't find 100% proof of that.