# How to extract a list from html with selenium and then use it in python script to find elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hidden, webdriverwait

Im trying to extract a list from webpage using selenium and python. I need to import it as list in order to find elements inside that list later using python code.

this is how its stored in the webpage:

```
...<input type="hidden" name="GridContainerDataV" value="[["7131090","Arvejas, Enteras Verdes","400","",""],["71311099","Arvejas, Enteras Azules","520","abril/2021","mayo/2021"],["71311100","lo que sea","720","junio/2021","diciembre/2021"],...]]" autocomplete="off">
```

This is how I tried to extracted (Im super begginer in python):

```
try:
    tabla = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "GridContainerDataV")))
    print(tabla.value)
```

Comment: What is the error currently?

Comment: .get_attribute('value') would get the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list:

```
[["7131090","Arvejas, Enteras Verdes","400","",""],["71311099","Arvejas, Enteras Azules","520","abril/2021","mayo/2021"],["71311100","lo que sea","720","junio/2021","diciembre/2021"],...]]
```

is the *value* of the *`value`* attribute of the `<input>` tag and is **hidden**. To extract the list you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [`presence_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65556520/scraping-dynamic-information/65560300#65560300) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `NAME`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "GridContainerDataV"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='GridContainerDataV']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='GridContainerDataV']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `get_attribute` function

```
try:
    tabla = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "GridContainerDataV")))
    print(tabla.get_attribute('value')
```